Using null values in supabase-golang
Hi Im new at Go I was trying to implement null values as a column value in supabase-golang
https://github.com/nedpals/supabase-go
var userResponse []helper.User;
userResponseError := supabaseClient.DB.From("users").Select("*").In("email",[]string{body["email"]}).Is("session_id", *helper.NullSessionID).Execute(&userResponse)

where I tried to create a nil pointer variable as NullSessionID = (*string)(nil) but this showed http: panic serving [::1]:58839: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference Error. Does anyone know a way to implement null value in supabase database or any repo I could use for implementing this specific usecase?
I tried using Null values as column values of a supabase database here I tried creating a nil pointer variable but showed the above error how can I implement such a usecase??
